# Selenium IE support for locator access using XPATH

Tags: xpath, selenium, browser-automation

I am trying to locate htmp/jsp web element using xpath. I am using Selenium testing tool and its library to access web element (findElementByXPath()). I am keep getting error as given below:

Unable to find element with Xpath ==

Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: What is the xpath that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I think the XAPTH expression is not correct so that selelnium is unable to find the element by using it.
You can get XPATH expression by doing this:
    1. Open Selenium IDE -->Options-->options-->Locator Builders-->put the xpath:position on the top. Now Selenium IDE could record the element's XAPTH expression,just copy it to you script.
    2.Download the Firebug plug-in in firefox ,It is very good tool that can locate element by XPATH, CSS,id,name and so on.